# How can I find all servers on the local network?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I want to design a software in java. I have a client program in my personal computer which is located in a LAN. In other pcs of this LAN server application has been installed. So the image of my system is like this:

[image: Client Server]

Ok, in this system servers have not same port , because some ports may close in each system, these servers just listen to a connection after finding an open port , as well Client doesn't know their IP, but as I mentioned all of these servers and client program are located in a LAN, picture of client program is some thing like this:

[image: Client]

When I click the `Scan NetWork` Button , Client should find all of the listener servers in network , what should I do in this case? Is it possible to find all listener servers with a client in a network with cause I'm new to networking.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have designed a simple Client Server socket programming . but this question is for another project . some thing like IDM but not based on Threads . It's  based on network nodes

Comment: To be useful, a server must listen on a predictable port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is some kind of [zero-configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) instead, like [Bonjour/Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) or [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). There are several Java implementations for both, as well as lots of native implementations on almost all OS.

They both solve your problem of finding the servers without knowing their IPs or ports.

Comment: thanks buddy, I voted you but i will check your answer. thank you for answering